# Embedding LuaJIT module into C application

Tags: lua, luajit

In my application, I have all the Lua libraries exposed from the C backend. Now, I have a need to load a Lua module. The method for this seems to be :

```
lua_getglobal(L, "require");
lua_pushstring(L, libname);
lua_pcall(L, 1, 0, 0);
```

which will search the `package.path` to find `<libname>.lua` and load it.

Is it possible to *build-in* the Lua module into the C application (so that the module becomes part of the C application) ? so that I don't have to separately package the Lua module. Somehow I am not able to find any references or examples of this! :(

p.s. I am using `LuaJIT-2.0.2`, and the library in question is `SciLua/Time` (uses `ffi`)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running luajit object file from C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19416981/running-luajit-object-file-from-c)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

```
luajit -b Module.lua Module_bc.c
```

will compile a module to bytecode and output a C array initializer containing that bytecode.
If you build with shared libraries enabled and export this array from the main executable, `require` will find it (and will not need to look for `Module.lua`.)

To test that it is working, set `package.path = ""` before `require`ing the module.  If it still works, you know the preload is working and it is not just using the `Module.lua` file from the current directory.

http://luajit.org/running.html

Other things to keep in mind:

- If the module depends on an external file (using `io.open`), that file still needs to be present.  For example some ffi modules try to open a C header file, to pass to `ffi.cdef`
- You need to keep `Module_bc.c` in sync with `Module.lua`, e.g. with a Makefile recipe, or you will see some confusing bugs!

Comment: I get the idea, and I saw the other post referred to by Mike, as well. But in my application I don't intend to use any shared libraries. So, my understanding is that, I need the `luajit` generated BC array, and I need to do `package.preload`, but I *don't* want the scripts to invoke `require`, so I also need to do `lua_getglobal(L, "require");lua_pushliteral(L, "module")` on the Lua state. correct?

Comment: If you don't want the script to invoke `require`, you will also need to store the module object in the global table.  And maybe use `luaL_loadbuffer` instead of `require`.  And generate a `.h` file instead of a `.c` file from `luajit -b`, because the `.h` version includes a length field but the `.c` version does not (and you need the length to pass to `luaL_loadbuffer`.)